# Installation Error of Omnet++ 4.6

Tags: omnet++

I am newbie in omnet++ platform.Firstly I install 4.4.1 version.after releasing  4.6 I deleted all files regarding omnet 4.4.1 and try to install by clicking mingwenv.cmd file in omnet 4.6 but it creates error as shown in picture attached in below

[image: picture].

Answer (score 0):

Some changes might have been introduced since 4.4.1 version.

Follow the second chapter of this guide: http://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf

Then report back for issues.

Note: installing OMNeT++ in a Linux based machine is much better in the long run. Consider having a virtual machine with OMNeT++ on it.